# Why does the function behave like this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def change(li):
    li[1] = li[1] + 2
    li = [3,3,3,4,5]
li = [1,2,3,4,5]
change(li)
print(li)
```

In the above code, shouldn't the function overwrite the input string completely ?
The output however is :
[1, 4, 3, 4, 5]

That is, the original string was modified and printed instead of being overwritten.

Comment: Please search for _local vs global scope_. There are many good examples out there.

Comment: Reassigning the local variable `li` inside your function does not affect the value of a similarly named variable outside your function.

Comment: You can use `li[:] = [3, 3, 3, 4, 5]` to overwrite the contents.

Comment: ```print(id(li))``` inside the function & outside of the function, u can see both are different objects

Comment: Really interesting. Is this something that is caught by pylint/a linting program? I've ran into these issues before fixed it somehow but did not understand why it was happening. Seeing this question I now understand but it isn't really intuitive. It printing `[1, 4, 3, 4, 5]` isn't an output I expect it to print but I now understand why.

Comment: You really should read the [Ned Batchelder's great post](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) Note, this isn't really mysterious, and it's all well documented. `li[1] = li[1] + 2` **mutates** the object being referred to by the local name`li` so of course, any other references to that object will see this mutation (duh). The fact that there is a global variable with the same name,`li`, *is totally irrelevant*. On the other hand, when you do `li = [3,3,3,4,5]` you are simply assigning a new object to the local name `li`. Of course, that doesn't affect the global name.

Comment: Note, you aren't working with strings, but lists...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python it's all references 
on the second line of the function `li = [3,3,3,4,5]`
you created a new object and reffered it with the `li` symbol of the local function scope
the `li` symbol still points to the original list object
you can figure out which object a symbol points to using `id` it is *similar to* memory addresses in C

```py
In [3]: def change(li):
   ...:     li[1] = li[1] + 2
   ...:     print(id(li))
   ...:     li = [3,3,3,4,5]
   ...:     print(id(li))
   ...: li = [1,2,3,4,5]
   ...: change(li)
   ...: print(li, id(li))
4476810336
4476742144
[1, 4, 3, 4, 5] 4476810336
```

Answer (score 0):

This is about scoping. You reset the li object within the function local scope.
It will not affect the global-scoped li-object.

Answer (score 0):

Variables defined outside functions are global functions and those defines inside functions are local variables. Both are different.